# C# - Facebook login keep the same profile when i want to connect

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm using api Facebook Login to get some informations from facebook like name, email, birthday ... 
My problem is that facebook propose to me the same profile to connect, so i cant change another account ? 
You can check this picture: (it's the same account always)

[image]

If you can help me please ? i can put the code if someone need it

**EDIT:** the code

```
using Facebook;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InterfaceGraphique
{
    public partial class WebBrowserForm : Form
    {
        private readonly Uri _loginUrl;
        protected readonly FacebookClient _fb;

        public WebBrowserForm(FacebookClient fb, string appId, string extendedPermissions)
        {
            if (fb == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fb");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appId))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("appId");

            _fb = fb;
          _loginUrl = GenerateLoginUrl(appId, extendedPermissions);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public FacebookOAuthResult FacebookOAuthResult { get; private set; }

        public WebBrowserForm(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
            : this(new FacebookClient(), appId, extendedPermissions)
        {
        }


       private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
        {

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.client_id = appId;
            parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

            // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
            parameters.response_type = "token";

            // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
            parameters.display = "popup";

            // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
                parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;

            // when the Form is loaded navigate to the login url.
            return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        }

        private void WebBrowserForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          webBrowser1.Navigate(_loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // whenever the browser navigates to a new url, try parsing the url.
            // the url may be the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication.

            FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
            if (_fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Url, out oauthResult))
            {
                // The url is the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication
                FacebookOAuthResult = oauthResult;
                DialogResult = FacebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess ? DialogResult.OK : DialogResult.No;
            }
            else
            {
                // The url is NOT the result of OAuth 2.0 authentication.
                FacebookOAuthResult = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code of mainForm:

```
private void btnFB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fbWebForm = new WebBrowserForm(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
            fbWebForm.ShowDialog();

            getInfosFacebook(fbWebForm.FacebookOAuthResult);
        }
   private void RecupererInfosFacebook(FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult)
    {
        if (facebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            _accessToken = facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken;
            var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);

            fb.AccessToken = token;

            //show user's profile picture
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me/?fields=birthday,email,name");
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(me.birthday) + me.email + me.name);
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried logging out your facebook?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i can't , when i press on "continuer", the form is closed and i return to the main form

Comment: i mean, go to your facebook account, then logout.. you can do that using any browser, not by using your app.

Comment: i have logout, but it's not working :/

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: I have add it to my post

Comment: not really sure, but can you try `webBrowser1.Navigate(_loginUrl);` instead of using `AbsoluteUri`?

Comment: No sorry it's not working, but i think i should something to delete cookies